# What is the difference between #define name and #define name(arguments) when it comes to #ifdef name or #if defined(name) in C?

Tags: c, macros, embedded

I've been working on an embedded C project for a few days and I've found some interesting configuration files that use a lot of macros.

The code looks like this

```
// config.h   
//????? 
#if defined(CONFIG_PERIPH_0)
#define CONFIG_PERIPH_1(ch, interrupt)
#elif defined(CONFIG_PERIPH_1)
#define CONFIG_PERIPH_0(ch, interrupt)
#endif
 
       CONFIG_PERIPH_0(PERIPH_INPUTCHAN_28, FALSE)
       CONFIG_PERIPH_0(PERIPH_INPUTCHAN_27, FALSE)
       CONFIG_PERIPH_1(PERIPH_INPUTCHAN_29, TRUE)
       CONFIG_PERIPH_1(PERIPH_INPUTCHAN_30, FALSE)
//?????
#undef CONFIG_PERIPH_0
#undef CONFIG_PERIPH_1

// periph.h
#include "config.h"
#define CONFIG_PERIPH_0(ch, interrupt) { \
    .interruptEnable = interrupt, \
    .channel = ch \
},
periph_chan_config_t const PERIPH0_Array_Chs[] = {
    #include "config.h"  // the contents of "config.h" file is copied here
    {FALSE, 0};
};

#define CONFIG_PERIPH_1(ch, interrupt) { \
    .interruptEnable = interrupt, \
    .channel = ch \
},
periph_chan_config_t const PERIPH1_Array_Chs[] = {
    #include "config.h"  // the contents of "config.h" file is copied here
   {FALSE, 0};
};

#define SIZE_PERIPH0_ARRAY (sizeof(PERIPH0_Array_Chs)/sizeof(PERIPH0_Array_Chs[0]))
#define SIZE_PERIPH1_ARRAY (sizeof(PERIPH1_Array_Chs)/sizeof(PERIPH1_Array_Chs[0]))
```

I don't understand what really happens inside these //?????? //?????? "tags" in config.h.
Also I am not sure if *#if defined(CONFIG_PERIPH_0)* is evaluated as TRUE or FALSE because before it, there is *#define CONFIG_PERIPH_0(ch, interrupt)...*
After running preprocessing the generated arrays are these

```
 periph_chan_config_t const PERIPH0_Array_Chs[] = {
      { .interruptEnable = 0u, .channel = PERIPH0_INPUTCHAN_28 },
      { .interruptEnable = 0u, .channel = PERIPH0_INPUTCHAN_27 },
      {0u, 0};
 };
 periph_chan_config_t const PERIPH1_Array_Chs[] = {
      { .interruptEnable = 1u, .channel = PERIPH1_INPUTCHAN_29 },
      { .interruptEnable = 0u, .channel = PERIPH1_INPUTCHAN_30 },
      {0u, 0};
 };
```

I wrote an example to highlight the difference between *#define name* and *#define name(args)* in terms of evaluating *#ifdef name* or *#if defined(name)* in both cases [MACROS](https://www.onlinegdb.com/edit/B1BEfhrwD)

Comment: The only difference between `#ifdef` and `#if defined` is that `#ifdef` requires fewer letters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: That will come as a surprise to somebody who has `#if defined X && Y == 3` and changes it to `#ifdef X && Y == 3`.

Comment: The `#ifdef` preprocessor instruction tests if the symbol (macro) is defined (or already exists).  It does not test the value of the symbol.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews in the simple case, that is true, but the `#if defined` syntax introduced with ANSI C,  a.k.a. C89 allows more complex tests such as:  `#if (defined XX || defined YY)  && !defined ZZ` for example.

Comment: Looks like a perfect example of how to write bloatware. Using includes in the middle of an initializer list is plain horrid design. A better design might be to create two or more struct initializer list, then depending on an #ifdef use the relevant initializer list for the struct. KISS principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in “config.h” appears designed for some earlier code to define `CONFIG_PERIPH_0` or `CONFIG_PERIPH_1` but not both.

If `CONFIG_PERIPH_0` is defined, this code defines `CONFIG_PERIPH_1` to be null—any use of `CONFIG_PERIPH_1(…)` is replaced with nothing (an empty token list). Conversely, if `CONFIG_PERIPH_1` is defined, this code defines `CONFIG_PERIPH_0` to be null.

Then the code uses both `CONFIG_PERIPH_0` and `CONFIG_PERIPH_1`, knowing that the one that was defined by the earlier code will be replaced as defined and the other will have no effect.

Whether a macro is defined as object-like (`#define foo replacement-tokens`) or function-like (`#define foo(argument) replacement-tokens`) is irrelevant to the `defined` operator or the `#ifdef` directive. If the macro is defined either way, the `defined` operator evaluates as true. If it is not defined, the operator evaluates as false.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the macro takes arguments or not does not affect whether it is defined or not.  The name alone is what you test for *defined*, the arguments are irrelevant because the macro is not expanded in the #ifdef / #if defined test.